# Need help calling a method with a click event listener

Tags: javascript, class, methods

Pretty much trying to call the select function inside my class, get error telling me select in not defined.

I tried this.element, as well as using an arrow function to call it.

```
class TabLink {
  constructor(element) {
    // Assign this.element to the passed in DOM element
    // this.element;
    this.element = element;
    // console.log(this.element);
    // Get the custom data attribute on the Link
    // this.data;
    this.data = this.element.dataset.tab
    // Using the custom data attribute get the associated Item element
    // this.itemElement;
    this.itemElement = document.querySelector(`.tabs-item[data-tab="${this.data}"]`);
    // Using the Item element, create a new instance of the TabItem class
    // this.tabItem;
    this.tabItem = new TabItem(this.itemElement);
    // Add a click event listener on this instance, calling the select method on click
    this.tabItem.addEventListener('click', select);
  };

  select() {
    // Get all of the elements with the tabs-link class
    const links = document.querySelectorAll('.tabs .tabs-links');
```

need select to be able to call this.

Answer (score 0):

`select` is a class method, you need to refer to it as an object property.

```
this.tabItem.addEventListener('click', this.select.bind(this));
```

If it doesn't refer to `this` in the method, you can just use `this.select` instead of binding it.